# iterate till the end of second array using python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

I have done something like this:

```
d = [('e', 0), ('f', 1), ('e', 0), ('f', 1)]
e = ['a']
d = [(n,j) for n,(i,j) in zip(e,d)]
d
[('a',0)]
```

I was just tryig to replace the equivalent tuple value with the array value, without changing the associated numbers. But the list only goes till the len of array `e` and not `d`. What I want to get as output is something like this:

```
d
[('a', 0), ('f', 1), ('e', 0), ('f', 1)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the unprocessed tail of `d` to the processed part:

```
[(n,j) for n,(i,j) in zip(e,d)] + d[len(e):]
#[('a', 0), ('f', 1), ('e', 0), ('f', 1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
[(n or i, j) for n,(i,j) in itertools.zip_longest(e, d)]
```

Check the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, yes, i did not saw the py3 tag, thanks!

Comment: you can drop `fillvalue=None` as this is default.

Answer (score 1):

If it's acceptable to mutate the original `d` list, I'd simply replace the first `d` tuples by iterating on `e`:

```
d = [('e', 0), ('f', 1), ('e', 0), ('f', 1)]
e = ['a']

for i, new_letter in enumerate(e):
    d[i] = (new_letter, d[i][1])

print(d)
# [('a', 0), ('f', 1), ('e', 0), ('f', 1)]
```

Note that Python tuples are immutable. `d[i][0] = new_letter` would fail with the error:

> TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

The above code modifies the `d` list in place by replacing old tuples with new ones. It cannot modify the old tuples.

Comment: I tried that too. It gave me error saying: `'tuple' object does not support item assignment` Hence I rejected the idea

Comment: seriously, my god. it worked too. I am still doubtful about myself what I made wrong, whereas I followed the similar process previously.

Comment: Yes.. I got it. The problem is with the assignment of value that I did. You have assigned the value like this `d[i] = (new_letter, d[i][1])` where as I assigned like this `d[i][0] = new_letter`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the zip function. The documentation says that (zip) "Returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables. The iterator stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted."

`[(n,j) for n,(i,j) in zip(e,d)] + d[len(e):]` should do the trick

Comment: Thank you for explanation. But let me edit your post for formatting properly.